# Folders created with Python code from 2 Colab accounts in one Google Drive shared folder in a small time period unexpectedly have the same names

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, shared-directory

There’s a Google Drive shared folder `shared_folder` where 2 different accounts can create folders with Python code run in Jupyter notebooks on Colab.

If one of these accounts try to create 2 duplicated folders, he will get an error:

```
import os
os.mkdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/shared_folder/test_folder')
os.mkdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/shared_folder/test_folder')
```

> FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/content/drive/MyDrive/shared_folder/test_folder'

But if those both accounts try to create the same named folder in a small period time in between - there's no any error and the behaviour is more than strange:

1. [In GDrive there're 2 folders with the same name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVERW.png)
2. [In Colab `Files` pane there're 2 folders with different names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0E4B.png)

> '/content/drive/MyDrive/shared_folder/test_folder' and '/content/drive/MyDrive/shared_folder/test_folder (1)'

3. I added marker files `first.txt` and `second.txt` into these folders and checked them under both accounts. So there's no consistency of postfix `(1)` appearing as we can see `first.txt` in both `test_folder` and `test_folder (1)` under different accounts:
   [acc 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEHVl.png), [acc 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rItu.png)

I'm looking for a solution which could provide me with consistent behaviour such as was described in the beginning when I got an error trying to create duplicated folder, but this time suitable for creating duplicates under 2 different accounts. In other words, I need to safely create folders in the same place under 2 different accounts.

As I understand, the issue is that GDrive has some lag in updating the second account with the information from the first one created something seconds before.

How would you solve this issue? Any thoughts?

Comment: if you know when a folder is being created you could add a pause or wait period before the second account reads/checks the folder's existence. If not, that might be an unavoidable limitation of using colab.

Comment: `if you know when a folder is being created you could add a pause or wait period before the second account reads/checks the folder's existence.`


@OriYarden The second account knows nothing about what happens on the other side.

Comment: Yikes... I would suggest making a separate file that is a list of names of (newly) created folders which is updated by that account as the new folder is created, then both accounts check the list prior to creating a new folder to confirm whether it would be a duplicate folder or not, as updating/reading a list would probably be "more instantaneous" than creating new folders so there would be less or no delay; but it might have the same issue (you'd have to run a test to see what actually happens... it might work). Otherwise, this might not be solvable.

Comment: @OriYarden, I've tried your suggestion - nope, it doesn't work. There still was a lag for about 20 (or even more) seconds. I've checked source code here https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/main/google/colab/drive.py hoping to find something wich could make an update on demand forcely, and looks like there was only `flush_and_unmount` method, and even it could help with force update, it's useless in my case because of `unmount` second part of the method)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised because I have had my own colab notebook that does something similar: creates new file in a new folder if it doesn't exist; if it does it opens/reads it and updates the the already created file with the newest data from an api call in the already created folder. Though this was within a single notebook and colab account rather than a shared colab account. I still can't imagine that a shared account would make all the difference... but maybe? *****Last idea: have the account that makes the new folder immediately read/open it (and the new file), that might "speed things up".

Comment: @OriYarden
>`I still can't imagine that a shared account would make all the difference...`
I made a file and add some text into it, waited till it became visible for both accounts, then I wrote a new line to the existed file under the first account and read that file under the second account, which didn't see any changes in the file for about 30 seconds - I clicked that code cell during this time till I finaly got an update))
Didn't get your last idea of having the account - could you please elaborate it?

Comment: Have the account that creates a folder/file/or updates a file immediately read/open that same folder/file/or updated file right after. So for example if acc1 updates the file, immediately after it does have acc1 read/open the updated file; from my experience with colab this should all work. Then (I'm assuming), acc2 will try to read/open the updated file and it should be able to given that acc1 was able to read/open the updated file.